# Copy cells by row containing text to column on another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to macros etc..and I've been trying to figure this problem out for a few days now!
I'm trying to go from a large spreadsheet of data, selecting specific cells based on the contents of specific cells, and paste into another worksheet.

**Source spreadsheet:**

Columns go: Site, Sub-location, Date, Month, Inspector, Action 1, Action 2 etc up to a max of 67 actions for each inspection.
Each row is a separate inspection submission

**Target spreadsheet:**

Columns go: Site, Sub-location, Date, Month, Inspector, Action, Due date of Action
where each row is a separate action.
I want it to skip pasting any values from the actions columns that would be blank (since no action is required). When it pastes the actions, it will also paste the first 5 columns (with site name, location, date etc), so that the action can be identified to the right site, date etc.

Hopefully that makes sense. By the end, I want the target spreadsheet to be able to be filtered by whatever the people need, e.g. by due date, or by location etc.

[image]

Code that I tried my hardest to get working...Unfortunately I can only get it working for the first row, and then it still pastes the blank (or zero) values and I need to filter them out. I'm thinking some sort of loop to do all the rows.

```
Sub test1257pm()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Corrective Actions").Select
    Range("A3:E3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Corrective Actions Tracker").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Sheets("Corrective Actions").Select
    Range("F3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Corrective Actions Tracker").Select
    Range("F3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("F4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$L$300").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "CMC to conduct clean of ceiling fans. Close out by 17/04/2014", _
        "Provide bins", "Send to contractor", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Many thanks to anyone that can give me any assistance! :)

*Edit:24-4-2014* 
Okay so after L42's code, it works fine if I could just consodidate my data first before putting it in the 1 column (stacking). The code I tried (using Macro recorder) is:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim r As Range
Dim i As Integer

For i = 3 To 10

Range("P" & i).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

Selection.Copy

Range("F" & i).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=3, Link:=1, DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
    IconFileName:=False

   Next i

End Sub
```

My problem with this is that it gives unexpected results...it doesn't consolidate it all into rows how I would expect. I'm thinking that this isn't the best solution...and probably the original macro needs to be changed..however I'm not sure how.

Comment: A couple clarification questions... 1. You want to take each row on your source sheet and (potentially) produce many rows on the target sheet, based on the number of actions logged in the source sheet. Is that correct? 2. Does your code need to parse out the due date from each entry, or is that left to the user? Thanks for the extra info!

Comment: Hi Dan, Yes that's correct. Potentially there could be many rows created from a single row. The original worksheet is over 200 columns though..so this is an easier way of viewing all of the actions :)
The due date is going to be inputted by the user manually, or possibly extracted from the actions cell using the =IFERROR(MID(E3,FIND("/",E3,1)-2,10),"-") formula if they inputted the date correctly originally. Thanks!

Comment: So basically you just wanted to put all actions in a `Column` right? Like you stack the actions with the same information on the first 5 columns `Site, Sub-Loc... etc.`, is that correct?

Comment: you want to build a **pivot table**. There seriously is no need to add so many spreadsheets and increase the size of file and slow down its speed of execution. You already have all the data you need on a spreadsheet you just need to be able to quickly "sort" and/or display it - use a pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overhaul #1:** Using the provided sample data

```
Option Explicit '~~> These two lines are important
Option Base 1

Sub StackMyActions()

Dim sourceWS As Worksheet, targetWS As Worksheet
Dim staticRng As Range, copyRng As Range
Dim inspCnt As Long, i As Long, fRow As Long, tRow As Long
Dim myactions

Set sourceWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Corrective Actions")
Set targetWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Corrective Actions Tracker")

With sourceWS
    '~~> count the total inspection
    '~~> here we incorporate .Find method finding the last cell not equal to 0
    inspCnt = .Range("A3", .Range("A:A").Find(0, [a2], _
        xlValues, xlWhole).Offset(-1, 0).Address).Rows.Count
    '~~> set the Ranges
    Set copyRng = .Range("F3:BT3")
    Set staticRng = .Range("A3:E3")
    '~~> loop through the ranges
    For i = 0 To inspCnt - 1
        '~~> here we use the additional code we have below
        '~~> which is GetCARng Function
        myactions = GetCARng(copyRng.Offset(i, 0))
        '~~> this line just checks if there is no action
        If Not IsArray(myactions) Then GoTo nextline
        '~~> copy and paste
        With targetWS
            fRow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            tRow = fRow + UBound(myactions) - 1
            .Range("F" & fRow, "F" & tRow).Value = Application.Transpose(myactions)
            staticRng.Offset(i, 0).Copy
            .Range("A" & fRow, "A" & tRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
nextline:
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

---

**Function to get the actions:**

```
Private Function GetCARng(rng As Range) As Variant
Dim cel As Range, x
For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Value <> 0 Then
        If IsArray(x) Then
            ReDim Preserve x(UBound(x) + 1)
        Else
            ReDim x(1)
        End If
        x(UBound(x)) = cel.Value
    End If
Next
GetCARng = x
End Function
```

**Results:**
1: Using your sample data which looks like below:

[image: Corrective Action Sheet]

2: Which after running the macro stacks the data like below:

[image: Corrective Action Tracker]

Above code only stack inpections with at least 1 Action.
For example, Site 3 which was conducted by MsExample do not reflect on the Corrective Actions Tracker Sheet since no action was posted.
Well I really can't explain it enough, all the properties and methods used above.
Just check out the links below to help you understand most parts:

[Avoid Using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)
[Using .Find Method](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx)
[Returning Array From VBA Function](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/returningarraysfromvba.aspx)

And of course practice, practice, practice.

Comment: Hi L42, thanks for your help. Unfortunately assumption 1 is incorrect, there will be gaps between actions. This is because the spreadsheet originates from a questionnaire form for inspection of a property, and if a particular item e.g. condition of floors is marked as unsatisfactory, then a corrective action needs to be inputted. If everything is fine (which is most of the time), then no actions. Often it will be Action 1....then Action 45...then Action 62..in 1 inspection. Hopefully that makes sense.
Also unfortunately there may not be any actions for a single inspection.

Comment: But yes, that is exactly how I want my data stacked! :)

Comment: I can get it working when the actions are put together (see link - red) however the actions will be spaced out (see link)
http://postimg.org/image/kh1mkig8t/

Comment: Cool. Ok got it. We might need to tweak it a little bit. And a possible solution can be found in the code you post using the `.Filter` method. Try to beat me to it? :)

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure how to use the .Filter method...so I tried to consolidate the data so your macro would work..but that didn't work either. (I put that code in the question above.) How did you go?

Comment: If it makes it easier, here is a sample of my spreadsheet 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kavwkg3dj8mzj23/Service%20Inspection%20Report.xlsm